# Unable to update Nullable field with Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Facing a strange problem with EF at the moment. I have a table in database with **nvarchar(MAX)** data type and is a **nullable field**. While updating the entries in the table when I assign null to this field its not saving that null, rather keeping the old value intact. But saving the empty string in it works. 
My code looks like this,

```
myobject.field1 = null; // assigning **null** here.
dbcontext.update();
dbcontext.saveChanges();
```

Any solution or guidance will be really appreciated.

**What I have tried:**

```
UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior
```

and

```
UseDatabaseNullSemantics
```

**EDIT:**

Found the culprit, Our application has Unit of Work and Repositories implemented and we have a base Repository which includes a update method like below,

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {

            //Ensure only modified fields are updated.
            _dbEntities.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            var dbEntityEntry = _dbEntities.Entry<T>(entity);
            foreach (var property in dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {               
                var current = dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property);
                if (current != null)
                    dbEntityEntry.Property(property).IsModified = true;
            }   

        }
```

In this function, updation is restricted in the null case. Though In my opinion this logic is invalid as it does not let the user change the existing value to null if user wants to.

Would love to hear the expert's opinion on this.

Sorry to bother you all.I am new to this kind of advanced logics and that make me stuck.

Comment: Please post the actual code you use to update the property.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I have added the code. Its a simple Update and Save.

Comment: Is `dbcontext.update();` a custom method? What does it do?

Comment: Did you get an exception?

Comment: @ChrisPickford Actually we are using UnitOfWork for handling entities. I have provided you the code to just give an idea of using standard methods of Entity Framework.

Yes, Update is a custom function written on the wrapper of context which attach the entity to context and update it.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom No, there is no exception.

Comment: @Vick we can't offer solutions when you don't provide all relevant code. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do we know what you did in context.update()

Comment: @ChrisPickford
Sorry to bother you guys. I have edited my question and provided the details. Would love to get my concepts clear by you. Please do give your remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do this:

```
myobject.field1 = null;
dbcontext.Entry(myobject).Property(x => x.field1).IsModified = true;
dbcontext.saveChanges()
```

Comment: You are right. The problem is kind of same as you mentioned. I have edited my question as well.